# How to run a long script and send constant feedback to an html dialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, client-server, google-sheets-api

In a Google Spreadsheet, I have a long script that permorms many actions in steps, like:

```
function MyLongScript()
{  
   var Results1 = Action1();
   //send feedback 1
   var Results2 = Action2(Results1);
   //send feedback 2
   var Results3 = Action3(Results2);
   //send feedback 3

   //end code
}
```

And I want to show the users a dialog box that tells them that script is running and updates each step of the scritp, like "Action1 complete", ..., "Action2 complete" and so on.

So, I have the HTML interface which contains some table rows with these steps. The question is: how do I make the dialog see that the code performed a certain step?

Right now I'm trying to start the code from the dialog after it loads:

```
$(function() {   

   google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(MainCodeSuccess)
      .withFailureHandler(MainCodeFailure)
      .MyLongScript();
}
```

And the dialog is called with the UI and HtmlService:

```
function CallDialog()
{
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FeedbackWindow')
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, "Dialog Title");
}
```

What I need is either a `getStatus()` in the dialog scritp or a `sendStatus()` in the server script.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple `google.script.run` calls to the server simultaneously.  You can't have one server call send multiple success calls back.  You could have your `MyLongScript()` run, save progress status somewhere, and just keep that running, then have a second `google.script.run` executing on a loop every certain time period.  You can use a JavaScript `setInterval()`:  `window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);`  I don't think that there is a jQuery equivalent.

So it might (roughly) look like this:

```
$(function() {   

   google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(MainCodeSuccess)
      .withFailureHandler(MainCodeFailure)
      .MyLongScript();

   window.setInterval("statusChecker()", milliseconds);

}

window.statusChecker = function() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(statusCheckSuccess)
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .StatuChecker();
};

window.statusCheckSuccess = function(returnStatus) {
  if (returnStatus !== false) {
    //To Do - show msg to user
    document.getElementById('idMsgToUser').textContent = returnStatus;
  };

};
```

Your `MyLongScript()` might need to be saving the state of the current status to a file.  I'm not sure if the subsequent, and simultaneous `google.script.run` calls wipes out the data in a global variable.  If a global variable would hold the data even with all the simultaneous server scripts running, you could save the current status to a global variable.  You'd need to experiment with that, or maybe someone knows the answer to that question.

Comment: That is a good idea. (And the only one I could find so far). I'm now having some issues on whether I should transfer the `spreadsheet` object to the window (and how to do that), because I cannot rely on `getActiveSpreadsheet` once user decides to change windows while code is running.

Comment: So, the Apps Script is not part of (bound) to the spreadsheet?  Maybe you could get the spreadsheet ID, and then store it somewhere?  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getId())  Then get the spreadsheet by the ID.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by storing the spreadsheet object in the window?  In the browser, you can use the DOM which has a window object.  Apps Script doesn't have a window object.  You can store data in the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)